# Vue Test Utils vs. Vue Testing Library

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm willing to learn how to unit test a Vue application.
On the official documentation, they incite new comers to use [Vue Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro) instead of the official [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org):

> if you are new to testing Vue applications, we would recommend using Vue Testing Library, which is an abstraction over Vue Test Utils. [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/testing.html#Recommendations)

However, when I browse GitHub projects, I didn't find a single very active project using the Vue Testing Library.

Why isn't it widely used ? is there a technical detail or limitation I'm missing ?

Comment: This isn’t a programming issue with a canonical solution. It’s opinion-based.